# Filtrar valores de dos columnas diferentes en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos de la que quiero recuperar unos datos y en *MySQL* pongo esto:

```
SELECT ranking.categoria, ranking.club, ranking.dni, ranking.foto, ranking.nombre,
  ranking.apellidos, ranking.posicion, ranking.posicion1, ranking.posicion2,
  ranking.posicion3, ranking.posicion4, ranking.posicion5, ranking.posicion6,
  ranking.posicion7, posicion8, posicion9,
  SUM( ranking.posicion + ranking.posicion1 + ranking.posicion2
    + ranking.posicion3 + ranking.posicion4 + ranking.posicion5
    + ranking.posicion6 + ranking.posicion7 + ranking.posicion8
    + ranking.posicion9
  ) as total 
FROM rankingwebpeque2019 ranking 
WHERE ranking.ano = '2019' AND ranking.genero = 'Femenino' 
AND ranking.categoria = 'Alevin' AND ranking.categoria = 'Infantil' 
AND NOT ranking.club = 'SEGURO 1 DIA' 
GROUP BY ranking.dni 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Quiero hacer funcionar esa consulta, en la misma consulta quiero traer obligatoriamente los valores que sean `categoría = "Infantil"` y la `categoria = "Alevin"`.

Con los dos `like` no funcionan porque me obliga a hacer un `OR` y solo me saca uno de los dos valores. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener los dos valores?

Comment: Y no, no va a funcionar porque SQL funciona fila a fila, y una fila no puede tener en el mismo campo el valor Alevin e Infantil. Podes aclarar un poco mejor que queres? como puede ser que un solo campo tenga las dos categorias? porque el OR no funciona?

Comment: En la misma tabla guardo varias categorias de diferentes personas, cuando quiero filtrar por diferentes categorias hay veces que necesito hacerlo a traves de varias categorias y no de una, en este caso es para un ranking de puntos y lo realizo con varias categorias, tal y como estaba haciendolo yo el OR no funcionaba como queria porque me mostraba solamente una categoria y no las 2, de la forma que me mostro Roger Torné, si que funciona el OR para mostrar las 2 que quiero.

Comment: Me llamó la atención que dice `LIKE` pero en el _SQL_ no hay nada sobre `LIKE`, quizás hay algo que no estoy entendiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes poner un `OR`, pero separando el resto de `AND` por paréntesis. De esta forma aparecerán todos los registros que cumplan las condiciones o que sean 'Infantil' y 'Alevin'

```
AND (ranking.categoria = 'Alevin' OR ranking.categoria = 'Infantil')
```

La consulta completa:

```
SELECT ranking.categoria,ranking.club,ranking.dni,ranking.foto,ranking.nombre,ranking.apellidos,ranking.posicion,ranking.posicion1,ranking.posicion2,ranking.posicion3,ranking.posicion4,ranking.posicion5,ranking.posicion6,ranking.posicion7,posicion8,posicion9,SUM(ranking.posicion+ranking.posicion1+ranking.posicion2+ranking.posicion3+ranking.posicion4+ranking.posicion5+ranking.posicion6+ranking.posicion7+ranking.posicion8+ranking.posicion9) as total 
FROM rankingwebpeque2019 ranking 
WHERE ranking.ano = '2019' AND ranking.genero = 'Femenino' 
AND (ranking.categoria = 'Alevin' OR ranking.categoria = 'Infantil')
AND NOT ranking.club = 'SEGURO 1 DIA' 
GROUP BY ranking.dni 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es usar el operador [`expr IN (value1, ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

> Devuelve 1 (*verdadero*) si `expr` es igual a cualquiera de los valores en la lista IN (), de lo contrario devuelve 0 (*falso*).

#### Ejemplo

```
AND ranking.categoria IN ('Alevin','Infantil')
```